# What does break someone's nose mean.

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching a game and this happend.

The gameplayer got in a dialog with and another player.

Player 2 - (That said. you gotta break someone's nose, you break my nose.

There were two options for player one. He could say two things
(We can start with that if you want)
( I didn't come to break someone's nose) 
Does you know what he mean.

I'm sorry my english is really bad because i'm from the netherlands if you can correct me do it so.

Comment: A nose is a bone. Does that clear things up?

Comment: No, because this is a phrase or somewhat

Comment: What do you think it would be if all the sentences were in your native language? This question doesn't seem to be about English, per se,but about logical responses.

Comment: Thank you for providing details. The problem is, this question might be "completely answerable with a dictionary", and so it would be considered [off-topic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I assume you know what a _nose_ is. Did you search the verb [_break_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/break?s=t) using a dictionary?

Comment: @DimeXYouDo A link to a "dictionary of dictionaries" is right **[here.**](http://onelook.com/?w=break&ls=a) Use it whenever you don't understand a word in English. After using a dictionary, if you _still_ don't understand, we hope you will ask another question here!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like he's saying that whatever responsibility there is to bear, he bears it (see also: "the buck stops here"). Whether this is literally breaking noses (i.e., punching them in the face so hard their nose literally breaks) or roughing people up or just asking questions, he's saying you have to do it through him (and not, presumably, those he represents).

"Break someone's nose" is not an English idiom with a hidden meaning, but it might be a euphemism for violence in general.

Comment: _Break someone's nose_ cannot be a "euphemism" for violence, since it _describes_ violence. A euphemism substitutes an indirect expression for a direct one. "Mature content," for example, is a euphemism for pornography.

Comment: I think that's how it's being used, though -- "breaking nose" being a milder and less direct expression for the actual level of R-rated violence that may be getting referred to. It doesn't seem fitting to call it a metaphor since noses might literally get broken but it's also not meant to be a literal expression, as in "You gotta break someone's nose, you break my nose. Punching of stomachs is the next guy over and groin kicking is down the other hall." So....euphemism?

Comment: Interesting question. _Metaphor_ is closer, maybe, but whatever we call it, it is **not** a _euphemism._